# Changed home directory permissions on remote server, can no longer ssh into it

Tags: ssh, permissions, ssh-keys, home-directory

I changed the permissions on my `~` directory, and according to [this question about ssh and home directory permissions](https://superuser.com/questions/466114/ssh-and-home-directory-permissions) I can no longer ssh into my remote server because it rejects my public key.

Is there any way to resolve this issue without having to spin up a new server?

Comment: Do you have any other account on this server you can log into?

Comment: Whenever making changes to your home folder, it's always a good idea to try to log back in from a new terminal shell while you're still logged into the existing session. This way you can fix any problems while you're still logged in.

Comment: @jmort253 yea good idea. I had no idea at the time that changing permissions on the home directory would affect public key authentication.

Comment: Ouch! If you don't have any other way to log in yourself (password-based authentication?), I would guess you're out of luck. The only other thing I can think of is getting another user to `ssh` in and then `su` from there (root, if you can).